# How Many License Numbers Consist of $4$ digits and $4$ letters, where one letter or digit is repeated?

Tags: combinatorics

If license numbers consist of four letters and four numbers how many different licenses can be created having at least one letter or digit repeated?

$$26 \cdot 26 \cdot 26 \cdot 26 \cdot 10 \cdot 10 \cdot 10 \cdot 10 = 4569760000$$

Is this right?

Comment: You should consider permutations of letters (L) and numbers (N). For example, LLLLNNNN, LNLNLNLN, NNNNLLLL, ... - are different.

Comment: @Oleg567 so you are saying the answer is?

Comment: @Oleg567 Thank you for your comment. I didn't realize that.

Comment: @Alraxite so my answer is not right?

Comment: @suffix No, what you've calculated is the total number of licences which are of the form $\text{LLLLNNNN}$ where $\text{L}$ and $\text{N}$ denotes a letter and a number respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the licences are of the form $\text{LLLLNNNN}$ where $\text{L}$ and $\text{N}$ denote letters and numbers respectively:

Number of licences with no letters or numbers repeated:

$26\cdot 25\cdot 24\cdot 23\cdot 10\cdot 9\cdot 8\cdot 7$.

So, number of licences with at least one letter or number repeated:

$\text{Total number of licences} - 26\cdot 25\cdot 24\cdot 23\cdot 10\cdot 9\cdot 8\cdot 7$.

Where the total number of licences is $26^4\cdot 10^4$ which is what you calculated.

---

Assuming the letters and numbers can appear in any order:

You can obtain this answer by multiplying the answer obtained above by $\dfrac{8!}{4!4!}$ which is the number of permutations of $8$ things in which $4$ objects are of one kind and $4$ objects are of the other kind. This is the same as the answer given by Omnitic.

---

Please note that as pointed out by Omnitic, the following does not restrict the number of letters and digits to $4$:

Assuming the numbers or letters can be filled in any order (and are not restricted to be $4$):

The licences have $8$ places which can be filled in with a number or a letter. Thus each place can have one of $26+10=36$ values.

Now, number of licences with no letters or numbers repeated: $36\cdot 35\cdot 34\cdot\cdot\cdot 30\cdot29$.

So, number of licences with at least one letter or number repeated:

$\text{Total number of licences} - 36\cdot 35\cdot 34\cdot\cdot\cdot 30\cdot29$

The total number is given by $36^8$.

Answer (score 1):

If the licence plate is of the form $LLLLNNNN$ where L stands for letter and N for integer between 0 and 9 inclusive then no.

Number of ones with no repeats: $26*25*24*23*10*9*8*7=\frac{26!}{22!}\frac{10!}{6!}$ number with repeats= $26^4*10^4-\frac{26!}{22!}\frac{10!}{6!}$

However if the order of the characters is not restricted then it is $\binom{8}{4}26^4*10^4-\binom{8}{4}\frac{26!}{22!}\frac{10!}{6!}$ And it also depends on the alphabet you use and the number system ;)

Comment: Shouldn't it be $26^4\cdot 10^4$ instead of $27^4\cdot 10^4$?

Comment: yes, corrected, thanks

Comment: Your final expression's value, $\binom{8}{4}26^4*10^4-\binom{8}{4}\frac{26!}{22!}\frac{10!}{6!}$ doesn't match with my answer.

Comment: Oh, you are right. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

$$(26\cdot26\cdot26\cdot26) \cdot10^4=4569760000-(26\cdot25\cdot24\cdot23)\cdot(10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7)=353760$$

Because you have to subtract where the number/letter would not be repeated

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Please refrain from writing answers that reproduce previous answers on old questions.